# Jenkins Artifactory Plugin with ConanClient: huge BuildInfo refering unrelated packages returned by ConanClient

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, artifactory, conan

for some reason the `BuildInfo` object returned by the `ConanClient.run()` method contains references to a lot of unrelated Conan Packages as "modules". It seems these packages were also built on the same Jenkins slave but of course in different jobs.

This is a minimal example leading to the huge `BuildInfo` being published to the Artifactory:

```
def conanUploadClient = Artifactory.newConanClient()
def buildInfoTest = conanUploadClient.run command: "upload ${aliasID} -r ${remoteName}".toString()
artifactoryServer.publishBuildInfo buildInfoTest
```

All other previous Conan commands like `conan install` were executed with another ConanClient instance to make sure the wrong info about the unrelated packages is not carried over from these operations.

Here is a "control experiment" leading to a `BuildInfo` without any associated Conan Packages/"modules" being published to the Artifactory.

```
def conanUploadClient = Artifactory.newConanClient()
def buildInfoTest = Artifactory.newBuildInfo()
artifactoryServer.publishBuildInfo buildInfoTest
```

Where could this wrong information from other builds come from?

Conan 1.8.2, Windows 10, Jenkins Artifactory Plugin 2.16.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the Jenkins Plugin reads in the entire `$CONAN_USER_HOME/conan_log.log` and puts it into the `BuildInfo` returned by the `ConanClient.run()`. I removed the file before the build and the info is ok now.